# `net.DialUDP` connection's `net.Read` is receiving its own `net.Write` data

Tags: sockets, go, udp

I have a rather complex server-client setup where the server essentially acts as a relay for certain packets between two unique clients. Don't worry, I made a diagram, but here is the summary.

The packet starts with the server, goes to `ClientS`, then `ClientS` sends a packet back as response, which the server then relays to `ClientP`. Then upon receiving packet, `ClientP` send a different packet back to the server, which it then finally relays to `ClientS` (supposedly).

#### Diagram A

[image]

#### Problem (check edit after)

The annoying part is that this only works up until step #4. For some reason when the server does the final `net.Write` to the UDP connection, it is somehow picked up but server's own `net.Read` from #2 instead of the `net.Read` from `ClientS`. Another diagram illustrating the problem.

#### Diagram B

[image]

#### Code

In terms of the code from the server. I'm doing two `net.DialUDP`'s, each to dial a connection to the two clients. After that connection is "established", there is a `net.Read` waiting in a goroutine on each connection.

At the moment the code is a bit all over the place and I don't want to just dump it all here. However here are the functions for each of each step in the diagrams and how I'm dialing the UDP connections. (obviously it won't compile, but maybe enough to spot something?)

```
clientSConn, err := net.DialUDP(udpNetwork, localClientSAddress, remoteClientSAddress)
clientSConn.Write(b []byte) (int, error) { … // <------- #1
clientSConn.Read(b []byte) (int, error) { …  // <------- #2
clientSConn.Write(b []byte) (int, error) { … // <------- #5 this byte[] is read by #2 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

clientPConn, err := net.DialUDP(udpNetwork, localClientPAddress, remoteClientPAddress)
clientPConn.Write(b []byte) (int, error) { … // <------- #3
clientPConn.Read(b []byte) (int, error) { …  // <------- #4
```

#### Assumptions/Tests

- When I dial from local to remote address and do a write, the data can only go out TO the remote address given to dial. Same with read, data can only come FROM remote address of dialed connection.
- I started this project using `net.Listen` and it gave me much stranger results. `net.Dial` eventually solved most of my initial issues. Maybe I'm still confuse what the difference is?
- I tried `net.ReadFrom` and `net.ReadFromUDP`, but both gave me same result as `net.Read`.
- I tried `net.WriteTo` and `net.WriteToUDP`, but neither sent any data over to the clients.

#### EDIT (SOLVED!)

Turns out the issues was rather obvious and embarrassing. #5's `Write` isn't looping into `Read`, it was just doing #1 and #2 again since the connection for #1 and #5 is the same.

Comment: It seems very likely that there's another bug involved in your code, and the socket isn't putting the send datagram into the recv buffer. Without a [mre] there's probably not much we can do here.

Comment: @JimB based on your response, I'm assuming nothing out of the ordinary stands out as incorrect. So I'll do a few more tests and then throw together a minimal example. I realized maybe somehow the packet itself contains remote endpoint data? So next, I'll create a fresh packet every time to see if that helps my issue.